# Where can I find actual UK law paragraphs?

Tags: united-kingdom, legal-research

In case I want to try to check plain English interpretations of the law against the actual law.

Comment: Out of interest, is there something in particular that you are looking for?

Comment: SDLT regulations (April 2016 budget), but I thought I'd ask it as a general question as I couldn't find an entry on this stackexchange.

Comment: OK. My answer still stands - but the changes won't appear there until the budget proposals pass through Parliament, which will take a month or two. However, a plain English description will probably appear in the [relevant section of the Government's website](https://www.gov.uk/stamp-duty-land-tax/overview).

Comment: If you can't wait that long, you can read the proposed amendment in [yesterday's Commons Votes and Proceedings](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201516/cmvote/160322v01v2.htm) - search for "stamp duty" (motions 45-50). These will shortly then be published as the Finance (No. 2) Bill, and will appear in the [list of bills before Parliament](http://services.parliament.uk/bills/).

Comment: ...or failing that, do a search. There are lots of news articles examining and dissecting the latest changes. :-)

Comment: Thank you. The articles aren't specific enough. I had a look at the list of bills before Parliament (seems like a sensible place), but didn't spot it yet. I seek the bits referred to in the footnotes on p10 in this document: https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/509184/GuidanceNote_Final.pdf, so the place where the paragraphs are (Sch 4ZA FA 2003; 1st different footnote) and "Finance Bill clause, subsections (8) and (9)".

Comment: Is this not covered by the above link to Votes and Proceedings? If I understand correctly, motion 46 inserts Schedule 4ZA into FA2003, and so lists the whole thing. Subsections (8) and (9) refer to that schedule. (The [PDF version](http://www.publications.parliament.uk/pa/cm201516/cmvote/160322v01.pdf) of V&P may be easier to parse.)

Comment: You are right, it is at the end of point 46, missed it. Let me see if I can avoid missing the bits those amendments apply to!

Comment: Found it further up - thank you! Does it make sense to weave your comments into your answer, then we can delete/tidy these comments?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37441/discussion-between-steve-melnikoff-and-nsandersen).

Answer (score 2):

All extant UK statute law can be found on [legislation.gov.uk](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/), which is the official online repository for British legislation.

Most recent acts of Parliament and statutory instruments are accompanied by Explanatory Notes, which describe - in plain English - what the various parts of that piece of legislation mean.

Comment: "All extant" - that would be nice.  There is a major problem that amendments are not being applied sufficiently promptly ... but it's still the best we've got.

Comment: @MartinBonner: there is at least one better source: [Westlaw](http://legalresearch.westlaw.co.uk/inside-westlaw-uk/legislation/), which claims to "publish all new acts the same day they come into force and update all the affected statutes and materials within 48 hours". However, besides a 48-hour free trial service, it's not free. (Other services like this may exist; I'm not affiliated with Westlaw, etc, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The free source of legislation and case law in the United Kingdom is [BAILII](http://www.bailii.org) (British and Irish Legal Information Institute).

BAILII contains the text of judgements and legislation.
However, as for plain English interpretations of the law... that's possibly at odds with your question, which asks for "actual UK law paragraphs".

If it's actual UK judgements or legislation, it is possible that it will not be in plain English.

Comment: I was hoping to verify a couple of points in the plain English interpretations, so non-plain English is exactly what I am looking for, even if I may regret it.

Answer (score 0):

jimsug brought up BAILII, but it's limited. WestLaw and LexisNexis have more material, but you got to pay for them.

[BAILII - Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.bailii.org/bailii/faq.html#whatcase)

> #### Q. What case law can I find on BAILII?
>
> - For recent years (1996+), the case law available on BAILII is summarised [here](https://www.bailii.org/bailii/summary-cases.html).
> - For earlier years, BAILII is adding leading cases in the core subjects covered by academic law courses, with the benefit of funding from [JISC](http://www.jisc.ac.uk/): see [here](https://www.bailii.org/openlaw/introduction.html). (Copyright restrictions prevent BAILII from making all these judgments available in BAILII's database at this point in time.)

[BAILII - Frequently Asked Questions](https://www.bailii.org/bailii/faq.html#whatcase)

> #### Q. Why are there not more English High Court judgments available on BAILII?
>
> - There is a restriction on the number of English cases from Divisions of the High Court which can be added to the BAILII database which arises from the fact that the shorthand-writers who transcribe judgments which have been given verbally (as opposed to judgments handed down on paper) may own the copyright in the transcribed version of the judgment. Copies of judgments in published law reports may also be subject to copyright. This prevents the judgment being added to the BAILII database without the consent of the shorthand-writer or law report publisher. BAILII, being a free web site, has no funds with which to acquire a licence to copy and display the transcripts. BAILII continues to press for the system to be changed so that all judgments may be freely available.
> - Handed down first-instance decisions of the England and Wales and Northern Ireland High Courts are generally only provided to BAILII where the Judge giving the judgment indicates that they are of sufficient interest to be made available for publication on the Internet.
> - Copies of unreported English judgments which are not available on BAILII can be requested from the court, via the [transcript request form EX107](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/order-a-transcript-of-court-or-tribunal-proceedings-form-ex107).