# Where can I find UK law on the way through Parliament (with effect before it has gone through)?

Tags: united-kingdom

(Slightly different to this question: [Where can I find actual UK law paragraphs?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7949/where-can-i-find-actual-uk-law-paragraphs))

Basically, where can I find such details about laws that are "in-flight", more specifically laws that are on the way through Parliament to gain final Royal Assent, but will have effect before they do (unless they do not gain Royal Assent in the end)?

Comment: Do you have an example of a law that took effect before it received royal assent?

Comment: SDLT changes will be effective from 1st of April 2016, but will likely not have royal assent at that point.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for **Bills** or Draft Bills.

[Bills & legislation - UK Parliament](https://www.parliament.uk/business/bills-and-legislation/) — this lists them all.

> A Bill is a draft law; it becomes an Act if it is approved by a majority in the House of Commons and House of Lords, and formally agreed to by the reigning monarch (known as [Royal Assent](https://www.parliament.uk/site-information/glossary/royal-assent/)). An Act of Parliament is a law, enforced in all areas of the UK where it is applicable.