# UK Courts Question: What was the judges final decision that may be cited as precedent in these cases?

Tags: united-kingdom, contract-law, business, scotland

Sheriff Court at Kirkcaldy: David Boyack v The Royal Bank of Scotland  ( this case was referred to in the "Office of Fair Trading (Respondents) v. Lloyds TSB Bank plc and others (Appellants) and others (Respondents)" 2007
[link](https://publications.parliament.uk/pa/ld200607/ldjudgmt/jd071031/lloyds-1.htm)

The other related case is the ROGER MARSHALL and  GILLIAN MARSHALL vs  RETAIL INSTALLATIONS SERVICES LIMITED, TESCO PERSONAL FINANCE PLC &
BARCLAYS BANK PLC? (case no B94YJ831 heard at the County Court at Cardiff on 30th September 2016)
[link](http://queensquarechambers.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Marshall-v-Tesco-Judgment-Handed-Down.pdf)

Even this [site](https://www.bailii.org/cgi-bin/lucy_search_1.cgi?sort=rank&method=boolean&results=200&highlight=1&mask_path=scot/cases%20scot/legis%20scot/other%20uk/cases/UKPC%20uk/cases/UKHL%20uk/cases/UKSC&query=(david)%20AND%20(boyack)%20AND%20(v)%20AND%20(the)%20AND%20(royal)%20AND%20(bank)%20AND%20(of)%20AND%20(scotland)) gives no answer and that site was recommended in this answer 
 on Stackexchange:Law   [Where can I find actual UK law paragraphs?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/7949/where-can-i-find-actual-uk-law-paragraphs?rq=1)

I have searched google  to no avail.?

Comment: What you have linked are the decisions.

Answer (score 1):

The final decision is, in each case, the document you have linked.

There will be a format for citing the cases which may vary depending on where you are citing them, for example, UK cases in the UK use a slightly different citation then when they are cited from Australia or Canada etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the second, Welsh, case you refer to, the final decision is indeed the judgement you have linked; citations must be taken from that document and no other. The first is slightly different, being a Scottish case. Your link is to the appeal judgment in 'OFT -v- Lloyds'; this is the final decision, but not the decision in the case of 'Boyack -v- RBS', in which you say you are interested. I can't find that judgement quickly; it may not be online, or it may require a Scottish lawyer to find the right keywords (if 'costs' equals 'expenses', then 'judgement' may well have some other name.)

Part of your confusion may stem from the belief that there is a 'UK Courts System' using a single terminology; there are three different jurisdictions, as different as US States.